# Responsive Email (EDM) css for shadowed boxes, like paper

Tags: css, html-email

I am looking to create this effect for an email we send out: 
http://d3cbux4et72c14.cloudfront.net/wtd/test2.html

This article talks about CSS3, which is a pipedream for the email world, where most email clients do NOT support any modern technology and HTML tables are the way to go.

However, because this type of a box, which looks like a piece of paper apparently lifted up on a table (which is why the shadow all around it), requires the use of background images to create such borders on left and right.

At the top and the bottom, I can just use an image as-is, not as a background image, and make it 100% width via media queries. This will make the images representing the top and bottom of the table responsive.

But for the rest of the content table where height needs to be variable depending on the quantity of the content, how should I create such borders with shadows without CSS3?

One idea is that I could create just a simple line border for old email clients so that the css3 shadows only work in new email clients, at least, but 95% of our audience uses Outlook 2007 or 2010. Those email clients do not support css3, so the entire effort would be lost.

Any ideas or pointers? Especially for the running left and right shadow border.

Thanks!

Comment: Email kind of works like IE5 but with a lot of features removed.  You may be able to find something that works, but most things are solved with images and tables.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that broad concept. I was looking for more specific ideas for creating running borders on tables that will vary in width (responsive) and height (different content in them), while not being able to use background images because in outlook 2007/2010, backgrounds do NOT work. Thanks!

Comment: I have added a link to my own HTML version of the edm. It's not responsive even in a regular browser because the center section (with a background of the shaded left and right borders) breaks in mobile version. Would welcome any thoughts! Thanks!